# How to get website's https certificate on linux command line?

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate

I can use `wget` or a similar command line tool to get an HTTPS response from a server.

On Firefox/chrome browser, I can simply download the certificate in pem format through the user interface, then add it to my trust host list.
How can I download the same HTTPS certificate through the Linux command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/641396)

Just use [openssl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/openssl) command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.edu:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem
```